# Setting section width and height in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Why don't `<section>` elements accept width and height attributes just as `<canvas>` elements do?

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blaja/zLxUg/))

Comment: html elements, besides canvas has to be changed by css (styles) attribute; eg. `document.getElementById('selection_main').style.height = "250px";` http://jsfiddle.net/zLxUg/2/

Comment: I would recommend you include the relevant code in your post

Comment: Could you please explain the Reason for negative voting??

Comment: @user3168736: That was me with the downvote. Links to fiddle are fine, but as *supporting* content. I always imagine the post without the fiddle, and if this didn't have the fiddle it wouldn't be clear that OP is referrnig to javascript properties and not CSS styles

Comment: I agree with you @musefan. But explain the reason for down voting and let the OP know who has downvoted it. Then only OP can understand the reason and ll solve it. You specified the reason but i can't find it's you. Because beginners in SO ll get frustrated without knowing the reason ..

Comment: @user3168736: Well in fairness OP should get used to it. I could have started with "-1" or I could have not left a comment at all... like most usually do. More importantly, why has it been upvoted? twice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `section` is a direct subelement of [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) whereas Canvas is a [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) which also extends HTMLElement but adds those 2 properties.

A `section` element is meant to be styled used CSS (similar to divs) whereas `canvas` is supposed to more of a HTML + Javascript interaction

Answer (score 1):

I'd never recommend using javascript to style the look and feel of a HTML element, that's why CSS got invented for, right?

If you're really pushed for any reason to use it, then take a look at the js alternative below.

Try declaring the properties as you'd do with a normal HTML element (cross browser way to do it):

```
section.style.width = '250px';
section.style.height = '250px';
```

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/zLxUg/1/) working fiddle.

Comment: Would this be normally how you do it? I would normally use CSS. I would only manipulate the DOM using Javascript when I needed to change the styling dynamically.

Comment: Yes,I know for this, but I was thinking that width and height attributes should work just the same.

Comment: @MattHarrison Nope Matt, I wouldn't do anything like that, and neither recommend it, but the code above was just a "you could do it this way" answer for the OP. But I think the best answer is SlashmanX's answer so I'll get rid of mine :)

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu I don't think you need to get rid of it. Could just mention it as an alternative to using CSS in the answer?

Comment: @MattHarrison Yep, let's leave it as an alternative to CSS.